# Update Playlist Image Deezer API

Tags: deezer

Is it possible to update a playlist artwork image thanks the Deezer API ?
There's no specific information on how do that here => https://developers.deezer.com/api/playlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to update the playlist artwork with the Deezer API.

The only solution is to use the front website https://www.deezer.com/fr/playlist/(playlist_id)  --> Edit button

Comment: OK, is it something in your roadmap for the API ?

Comment: Sorry, not for the moment.

Comment: I have seen websites that can manipulate the playlists and edit the image and other playlist information. How do these sites edit the image?